# Cache Control code is not working with post request in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

i'm using this code for cache control.

```
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must- 
 revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
 response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.

 response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.

 if (request.getSession(false) == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
}
```

Comment: i'm using above code for cache control. it is working fine when GET request is coming but this code is not working with POST request.

Answer (score 1):

With refrence to RFC 2616 Section 9.5:

> "Responses to POST method are not
>   cacheable, UNLESS the response
>   includes appropriate Cache-Control or
>   Expires header fields."

So,you can cache POST request response but only if you add appropriate headers in it. You can set expiry time as below and try caching mechanism.

```
response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000L);
```

for proxy server

```
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

Comment: Hi Onkar Musale, i'm facing issue with the browser back button after logout. after logout when i click back button then we will see the previous page. to stop this i wrote that code which works fine(after clicking back button login page appear) when there is a get request , but when i'm using post method then after clicking back button an error page opening saying confirm form re submission. please help me this. i can also share my code with you.

Comment: If you are managing Session or Cookies  then you have to destroy the value of the current session or cookies after clicking on logout button and after that you have to write the condition whether this cookie or session is set or not, if it is not set then you have to redirect into the login page. Please accept answer if it helped you. Thanks and cheers...!!